# Add value to cell if condition is meet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with columns and rows like this example:

```
|   COLOUR   |   TO COLOR   |   DONE   |
 Red          Green          YES
 Blue         Yellow         YES 
 Yellow       Red            YES
 Blue         Green          NO
```

And another one with this structure:

```
|   COLOUR   |   OUT   |   IN    |
```

What I want to do, on the second sheet, every time a row is generated in the first sheet, I want to calculate for every colour how many went out and how many went in.

So, with that example, the second sheet looks like this:

```
|   COLOUR   |   OUT   |   IN    |  
 Red          1         1
 Blue         1         0
 Yellow       1         1
```

This is what happend:

1. Row 1: it was red and turn green so in the second sheet, in the row of **red** I need to add 1 to **OUT**
2. Row 2: it was blue and turn yellow so in the second sheet, in the row of **blue** I need to add 1 to **OUT**
3. Row 3: it was yellow and turn red so in the second sheet, in the row of **yellow** I need to add 1 to **OUT** and in the row of **red** I need to add 1 to **IN**

This happend with the rows who in the column of **DONE** is **YES**. For example, the fourth row is **NO** so I don't need to calculate this row.

How I can do this? I was trying with IF but I don't know how to use formulas in Google-Sheets.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: access to the sheet u mean?

Comment: if you can - yes. if not do: https://imgur.com/a/axxjpP8

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ejXY_fh7w7_JR7hAH8SODBsTHbVC-e2C-sV0NazmYWU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF('Hoja 1'!C2:C="yes"; 
 {'Hoja 1'!A2:A&"×1×IN"\'Hoja 1'!B2:B&"×1×OUT"}; )); "×")); 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 
  pivot Col3 label Col1'COLOUR'"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about simply couting the 'Reds' rows in the column?

Column A | Column B | Column C
red  | green  | yes
red  | blue  | yes
blue | red  | no

=COUNTIFS(A1:A99;"red";C1;C99;"yes") the result is the RED IN (total 2)
=COUNTIFS(B1:B99;"red";C1;C99;"yes") the result is the RED OUT (total 0)

Comment: According to your demo sheet:
=COUNTIFS('Hoja 1'!$A$2:$A$11;A2;'Hoja 1'!$C$2:$C$11;"YES")